# Error when clearing cache: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'cache_views' doesn't exist

Tags: views, caching

today I have almost successfully moved my Drupal website from localhost to a shared hosting account. Everything seems to work fine for now, except for 1 thing: anytime I want to clear Drupal's cache I get this error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'prevcer_drupal.cache_views' doesn't exist: TRUNCATE {cache_views} ; Array ( ) in cache_clear_all() (line 165 of /home/prevcer/public_html/drupal-7.26/includes/cache.inc).
```

The problem happens because I didn't import 'cache_views' table as it was giving me errors. The weird thing is I can import it now, but it breaks my site completely with these bunch of errors:

```
Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.
```

This error goes away as soon as I delete 'cache_views' table again, but the original problem stays.

I've tried multiple solutions (created blank 'cache_views' table, created same 'cache_views' table as 'cache', tried importing whole database again and again) but nothing helped.

Comments appreciated!

Comment: Import it, then truncate it, then clear the caches - that should sort it

Comment: I've tried that and I'm getting the "Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception," errors.

Comment: Hmm, definitely tried it in that order? Import cache_views, truncated cache_views, then clear the rest of the caches? If so, I'd say the new problem is unrelated to that one. Your error logs will give you proper details of the additional error, though

Comment: By "clear the rest of caches" do you mean on the website itself (Config- Development- Clear all caches) or in SQL by selecting Empty next to every table called cache?

Comment: Anyway, both ways don't work. It's funny because I only need to delete 'cache_views' and the site is working again, except when I work with Views or clear the cache.

Comment: Part of the problem is also that I am on shared hosting and can't control max_allowed_packages, which results into "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away'"

Comment: What is the Table Extension Name for Drupal in your Install?

Comment: Ah, that's almost certainly what the problem is - Views' cache strings are massive so you need a higher max_allowed_packet. The failure's happening when Drupal  tries to rebuild the cache and inserts to cache_views. I don't know that there's a way to fix that without upping the server var

Comment: Database name is 'prevcer_drupal', table name is shown as 'cache_views' but in the error log it was 'prevcer_cache_views'. I hope that answers it. Edit: that's what I'm afraid of, Clive.